How to move partitions using GParted in a live environment?
How to move partitions using GParted in a live environment of Ubuntu 23.10?
I've been trying to setup a dual boot on a Dell XPS, and after a failed updgrade from 22.04 to 24.04, I'm trying to clean up the disk partition on the computer.
This is what sfdisk - l give me
Périphérique        Début        Fin   Secteurs Taille Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1       2048     493567     491520   240M Système EFI
/dev/nvme0n1p2     493568     755711     262144   128M Réservé Microsoft
/dev/nvme0n1p3     755712  620066815  619311104 295,3G Données de base Microsoft
/dev/nvme0n1p4 1951266816 1954187263    2920448   1,4G Environnement de récupération Windows
/dev/nvme0n1p5 1954187264 1997178879   42991616  20,5G Environnement de récupération Windows
/dev/nvme0n1p6 1997180928 2000408575    3227648   1,5G Environnement de récupération Windows
/dev/nvme0n1p7  620066816 1951266815 1331200000 634,8G Système de fichiers Linux
/dev/nvme0n1p8 1997178880 1997180927       2048     1M Système de fichiers Linux

And this is the actual order from parted -l
Numéro  Début   Fin     Taille  Système de fichiers  Nom                           Drapeaux
 1      1049kB  253MB   252MB   fat32                EFI system partition          démarrage, esp
 2      253MB   387MB   134MB                        Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 3      387MB   317GB   317GB                        Basic data partition          msftdata
 7      317GB   999GB   682GB   ext2
 4      999GB   1001GB  1495MB  ntfs                                               diag
 5      1001GB  1023GB  22.0GB  ntfs                                               caché, diag
 8      1023GB  1023GB  1049kB  ext2
 6      1023GB  1024GB  1653MB  ntfs                                               caché, diag


How to get the partitions in the right order in Gparted? Or it is not useful to bother with that?
How to merge partitions 7 and 8 that I will be using to install a fresh Ubuntu? Should I move these partition to the end?
Do I need all 3 windows backup partitions?

Thanks!

Windows seems to need partitions, I would not change them. What is/was p8, that is relatively small? A boot partition? Most desktops do not need a separate /boot partition. I might just leave it, as you would have to move all the partitions inbetween so they are adjacent.  Also why ext2? Ext4 is now the standard amount many other Linux formats. If you are moving NTFS, only use Windows tools and run chkdsk afterwards.

@oldfred No Idea what was p8...

I'll switch to Ext4
